# how to pass local state value to store without having an event

Tags: react-redux

I'm very new to redux+React. I need to pass localstate to store. I was able to do it with mapDispatch and using a click event to trigger it

```
 <div className="form-group">
 <button onClick={()=>this.props.onValueClick(this.state)}  type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
   </div>   


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

    return {

        onButtonClick: () => dispatch({type:'UP'}),
        onValueClick: (data) => dispatch({type:'SET',value:data.Value})
    }
}
```

This code working fine. But What i need is i need to trigger this (pass local state to store whenever **local state is changed**. (in this example i have to click on a button..

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using local state instead of reading it from reduces store itself ?

Comment: Actually no special reason. But i dont understand how to trigger it.  Lets say i have a function in a component which generate some value.. how can i save it in the store using mapdispatch once the value is generated by local function.    In above exmple   we have onClick event but without a triggering  event how can we do it